# C# Does this object initiation call its constructor?

Tags: c#

```
private Object object1;
```

Does object1 call the default constructor of Object even though it haven't used `= new Object();` ?

If not, is object1 NULL until it is initialized with `new`?

Comment: Why don't you run the program and find out.  It'd take far less time to see if it's null or not by running the program than asking us.

Comment: Actually, writing a test program will be far slower than the fastest gun in the west :)

Comment: It took over a minute for a response, and likely several minutes just typing up the question.  You could write out a test program in easily 15 seconds.

Comment: But alas, workplace computers are running on Windows XP with 2gb ram. Booting up visual studio + compilation time would take over 5 minutes.

Comment: If you don't even have VS up, why do you need to know the answer to this question?  Clearly you're not actually programming anything, if you were, it would already be up.  And that's admitting to being pretty damn lazy, not even being able to wait for VS to load to get the answer to a programming question.

Comment: I'm reading a C# book, I wrote this with my phone.

Comment: Regardless, it's still extraordinary rude to make no attempt whatsoever to attempt to solve a problem before asking others to do your work for you when you were quite capable and able to solve the problem entirely on your own.

Answer (score 4):

No, that field declaration *just* declares a field. It will have a default value of `null`.

From section 5.2 of the C# 5 specification:

> The following categories of variables are automatically initialized to their default values:
>
> - Static variables.
> - Instance variables of class instances.
> - Array elements.
>
> The default value of a variable depends on the type of the variable and is determined as follows:
>
> - For a variable of a value-type, the default value is the same as the value computed by the value-type's default constructor (§4.1.2).
> - For a variable of a reference-type, the default value is null.
>
> Initialization to default values is typically done by having the memory manager or garbage collector initialize memory to all-bits-zero before it is allocated for use. For this reason, it is convenient to use all-bits-zero to represent the null reference.

If you want it to start off with a value other than null, you need to initialize it explicitly:

```
private Object object1 = new Object();
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of the class is not called and the field is `null` until assigned a different value.

The static constructor however might get called when loading the type.

Comment: Note that this isn't a property - it's a field.

Comment: static constructor won't get called until before a static method is called. I wouldn't expect loading the type to call the static constructor. Happy to be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

null is default for any reference type

you created object handle, you can assign any object reference to this handle.

Comment: I don't think "handle" is a useful term here. "Variable" or "field" make sense, but "handle"?